# ¿Cómo añadir un salto de linea entre dos bloque de código?

Tags: python

¿Cómo  añadir un salto de línea entre dos bloque de código?

Por ejemplo:

```
print("bloque1")

print("Aqui debería haber un salto \n")

print("bloque2")
```

El resultado que pretendo debería lucir así:

> bloque1
>
> bolque2

Lo que he hecho para buscar un solución es imprimir una cadena vacía `print(" ")`. El resultado a nivel visual es el mismo. ¿De qué otras maneras podría hacerlo?

Comment: no conozco python pero... no hay una funcion printn() o no puedes poner un codigo de salto de linea (tipo \n, por ejemplo) ?

Comment: Gracias por la corrección, print();) Ya traté de usar \n, fue mi primera opción, pero no podía... :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay varias maneras. Estas son algunas:

- Una opción es la que ya das, llamar a [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) con una cadena vacía, o mejor, sin argumentos:

  ```
  print("Hola")
  print()
  print("StackOverflow en Español")
  ```
- Añadir literalmente el carácter de nueva línea:

  ```
  print("Hola\n")
  print("StackOverflow en Español")
  ```
- Si imprimes una variable, puedes usar un [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals) o concatenarla (aunque es menos eficiente):

  ```
  var = "Hola"
  # Con f-string
  print(f"{var}\n")
  print("StackOverflow en Español")

  # Concatenando
  print(var + "\n")
  print("StackOverflow en Español")
  ```
- Mediante el argumento `end` de `print`:

  ```
  print("Hola", end="\n\n")
  print("StackOverflow en Español")
  ```
- Pasar `\n` como un segundo argumento:

  ```
  print("Hola", "\n", sep="")
  print("StackOverflow en Español")
  ```

  Funcionaría sin usar el argumento `sep`, pero añade un espacio al final de `"Hola"` ya que ese es el separador por defecto.

Comment: Thanks Maquina. Yo apenas llevo como 5 días con Python,y con la programación poco tiempo, ventajas de la cuarenta ;) Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente añadiendo el \n al final del primer print:

```
print("hola maria" + "\n")
print("hola paco")
```

mismo resultado que:

```
print("hola maria")
print(" ")
print("hola paco")
```

Comment: La segunda forma que mencionas tiene una pequeña diferencia, y es que el salto de línea tendría un espacio en blanco. :)

Comment: Ya, es una chapuza ':D

Answer (score 0):

Mi aporte

Colocando `chr(10)` = Salto de línea en ***ASCII***.

ó

`chr(13)` = Enter en ***ASCII***

```
print("bloque1"+ chr(13))
print("Aqui debería haber un salto" + chr(13))
print("bloque2" + chr(13))

print("bloque1"+ chr(10))
print("Aqui debería haber un salto" + chr(10))
print("bloque2" + chr(10))
```